# How to display multiple field from database inside autocomplete input

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, autocomplete

Hello here is my problem.

I have an autocomplete input that retrive data from my database that shows me an image and a text. What I want to do is add another text next to it but from another field. But when I try it doesn't find my image anymore.

Here is my code :

PHP FILE

```
  <input type="text" name="text" id="text" autocomplete="off"><br />

  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button"><br /><br />

</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function(){

    $('#ref').autocomplete({

      source: 'autocomplete.php'

    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
      return $("<li><div><img src='img/" + item.value + "' /><span>" + item.value + "</span></div></li>").appendTo(ul);
    };

  });
</script>
```

autocomplete.php

```
  require('db.php');

  $term = $_GET['term'];


  $q = $db -> prepare('SELECT data1,data2 FROM table WHERE data1 LIKE :term');

  $q -> execute(array('term' => '%'.$term.'%'));


  $array = array();

  while ($data = $q -> fetch()) {

    array_push($array, $data['data1']. ":".$data['data2']);

  }


  echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

So to be clear this is how i'd like it  to be shown in my input :

**MYIMG** **DATA1** : **DATA2**

Sorry if I'm not being clear enough.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you really have `<?php` right before you write the HTML form? That should throw some serious errors since the PHP parser will parse it as PHP, which it isn't.

Comment: Your image file name is same as data1, right? so now your filename is returning as "data1:data2" which is not the file name. Quick and dirty solution would be to split your item.value on colon : and use index 0 as image source. CORRECT way is to return proper JSON with data1 and data2 as separate properties and format them on client side.

Comment: No sorry i don't have it

Comment: Change the code to what you have then, please.

Comment: The problem is that i don't know much about javascript and JSON i found the code online and it worked. Is it correct if i do it like this ?

while($data = $q->fetch())

{

    array_push($array, $data['data1']);
   array_push($array2, $data['data2']);
}


echo json_encode($array2);

Comment: I think you need to remove space. change it `$q -> fetch()` like `$q->fetch()`.